# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng even after adding google-play-services_lib as a library project

Tags: java, android, adt, google-maps-android-api-2, eclipse-adt

I am trying to implement Google Maps in android, but whenever I run the app on the emulator it gives me the following `Error`:

```
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at com.example.directions.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:14)
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
06-25 02:21:52.890: E/AndroidRuntime(931):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Following is `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.example.directions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
static final LatLng position = new LatLng(21, 57);
private GoogleMap googleMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            }
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        Marker pos = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                position).title("My Position"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And this the `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
   <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have been searching for the solution for a long time. I have already added the Google Play services as a library: `File->Import->Existing Android Code into workspace ->Selecting the google play services lib -> Copy projects into workspace`

I have also added the project in `properties -> Library -> Add-> Google play services lib`.

Kindly help..Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you build path the library that you have added in your project ?

Comment: are you added permission sin manifest.xml file and you have to include that google play services library like this <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> just check the files once.

Answer (score 1):

include below line in android manifest

```
<uses-library android:required="true" android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```